# Could a security breach happen through Reflection?

Tags: c#, security, system.reflection

Assume you have a function in C# which allows you to print out the properties of a model like this:

```
public void Export<T>(List<T> list)
{    
    // get properties of Model
    Type modelType = typeof(T);
    var modelInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(modelType);
    PropertyInfo[] properties = modelInstance.GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        if (property.CanRead)
            PRINTOUT(property.Name);
    }

    foreach (var entity in list)
    {
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            if (property.CanRead)
                PRINTOUT(property.GetValue(entity, null));
        }
    }
}
```

Now, this function is in a controller so, as I've read, is a publicly exposed HTTP endpoint! Is it possible for a malicious user to ask to `PRINTOUT` properties he should not see?

To avoid this, I'd like to call this function from another controller which pass in a very specific type.

For example, `PrintoutCustomers` in the controller `Customers` calls that function while also the controller `Products` (with the action `PrintoutProducts`) can call the same exact function but pass in a list of products (instead of customers).

The user will then have a list of specifics publicly accessible HTTP endpoints and no one of them will allows him to do anything harmful.

I'd like that function to be **private** and **shared** between all my controllers: is it possible? Can I do that? Or do I really have to copypaste the same method everywhere I need it (and wasted my time tried to make it generic using typeof and reflections)?

Comment: There is no point doing this: `var modelInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(modelType);` you already have the type `Type modelType = typeof(T);` so just do `modelType.GetProperties();`

Comment: I've tried but that gives 2 different results! If I don't instanciate the class, for strange reasons the properties are different. If I don't instanciate I get a bunch of stuff I've never written in my life: if I do instanciate, I see the properties I've specified in the class.

Comment: @Saturnix: that really shouldn't be the case. There must be something else going on.

Comment: Then I think this will be object of another question since it is bugging me too... I swear that's what I saw: getproperties of type = crap. Get properties of instance = correct.

Comment: @Saturnix: Most likely, what you did was the following: `Type modelType = typeof(T); var properties = modelType.GetType().GetProperties();`. Notice the `GetType`? That's incorrect, `modelType` already is a type.

Comment: Considering how stupid I am, yeah... That could really be the case! As soon as I'll have time I'll try out not to instanciate the class to see if it works.

Comment: @Saturnix: Please link to your other question once you have created it, if you can reproduce the issue; I'd be interested in it and I think other readers of this question might be so, as it is related.

Comment: Daniel was correct - it works fine, probably I was getting the type of type. Should I post the answer anyway even if I already know the solution?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I think Daniel Hilgarth already found the answer. If you do `typeof(T).GetProperties()` you get all the properties of `T`. But if you do `typeof(T).GetType().GetProperties()` you get all the properties of an `internal class` inside `mscorlib` called `System.RuntimeType` which derives from the `public abstract class` called [`System.Type`, "the root of the `System.Reflection` functionality"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Right - that hadn't yet been confirmed by the time I wrote my comment. In that case, the *if you can reproduce the issue* restriction applies negatively and there are no open ends left :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you put that method in a controller? It belongs into a static helper class or something like this. You could even make it an extension method, if you want to go fancy.

```
public static class OutputExtensions
{
    public static void Export<T>(this List<T> list)
    {
        // get properties of Model
        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            if (property.CanRead)
                PRINTOUT(property.Name);
        }

        foreach (var entity in list)
        {
            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                if (property.CanRead)
                    PRINTOUT(property.GetValue(entity, null));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(This version also contains the fix suggested by Trevor Pilley in his comment)

You could use it like this in every controller:

```
listOfModels.Export();
```

Comment: my bad, I really suck at formatting code in SO since I can't use TAB. Very nice answer! Will try it out and mark if it works. Thanks!

Comment: @Saturnix you can always select the code and click the `{ }` in the toolbar. That will add the 4 spaces for you :)

Comment: @ColeJohnson: He did that, otherwise it wouldn't have been highlighted as code at all. The problem is that the different levels of the code are not properly indented.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Oh! The dreaded mixed spaces/tabs scenario -_-

Comment: @ColeJohnson: Yeah... SO really should offer ReSharper in its edit textbox ;-)

Comment: When dealing with JS or PHP I can use online beautifiers: didn't found a working one for C# - copypasta from IDE usually result in a mess.

Comment: @ColeJohnson: No, that wasn't a real suggestion, just a joke. Looking for an online beautifier was actually the reason why it took me so long to add that code... But I guess we are really going OT here.

Comment: I was in the meta spirit when I said that. I knew you were joking. Oh well. Time to delete obsolete comments.

Comment: I'd recommend removing the `print` calls here too and return a dictionary of property names and values which the controller can pass to the view to display.

Comment: @TrevorPilley: Yes, that would be a good idea, **if** it actually should be printed to the user. It could be as well that it should be printed to a log file or something else. Because I don't know the actual scenario, I will just leave it as it is.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, I think Shannon's maxim applies:

> *The enemy knows the system.*

This is normally cited in the context of cryptographic algorithms, but it works here too. Yes, this method provides malicious users with lists of stuff they might not otherwise know about, but in theory, they could also just query your server for all possible combinations of words and see which ones work; that would also give them a list of open endpoints.

When you leave your house, you don't put camouflage over your door - you lock it. The same principle works here: if there's something a user shouldn't be able to do, make sure your authentication and authorisation code works, and properly denies access to anything you want to keep them out of. Simply hiding things is known as *security through obscurity*, and in short, it doesn't work.

When you make software that can connect to the web, it's ok (and often a good idea) to hide certain things to reduce the attention they receive from attackers, but even then you should assume that at some point a malicious user *will* find out that they exist, and you should secure them against malicious use.

In your particular case, I'd say the following:

- Can you do without this particular functionality?
- Can you do it another way that exposes less of your system?
- Can a malicious user use this function to do something you don't want them to be able to do?

If the answer to any of these is "yes", then you should probably not do this. If and *only* if *all* of them are "no", then you're fine. Personally, I think you're forgetting a simple rule: if it doesn't need to be accessible from the web, don't put it in a controller! Consider moving this method to an internal class in your logic layer, somewhere that only your trusted code can get at it.

Comment: security through obscurity is definitely something I'd like to avoid: that's the entire sense of my question here. How can I make the function available to all the controllers but NOT to the users. The users may call it only through very specific public controllers which limits the actions of the function.

Comment: Put the function itself in another class, so your controllers can access it but the users can't. Then use logic in the controller methods to restrict the uses of this function to the specific uses you want. The users then can't call this method directly; they have to go through the controller, which rejects anything you don't like.